# Java Map sort by value

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator, treemap

I was looking for ways of sorting `Map<String, Integer>` by values. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java), which solved my sorting problem, but not exactly. According to the post, I wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

    static class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        Map<String, Integer> base;

        ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
            this.base = base;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        ValueComparator vc = new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(vc);
        map.put("A", 1);
        map.put("B", 2);
        sorted.putAll(map);
        for (String key : sorted.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " : " + sorted.get(key)); // why null values here?
        }
        System.out.println(sorted.values()); // But we do have non-null values here!
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A : null
B : null
[1, 2]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

As you can see from the output, the `get` method always returns `null`. The reason is my `ValueComparator.compare()` method never returns `0`, which I've figured out by making [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842830/treemapstring-integer-objects-get-method-return-null-value).

Someone suggested in that post the following to solve the `null` value problem:

```
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            if (base.get(a) > base.get(b)) {
                return 1;
            }else if(base.get(a) ==  base.get(b)){
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;  
        }
```

I've tested this piece of code and it introduces a key merging problem. In other words, when the values are equal their corresponding keys are merged.

I've also tried the following:

```
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                if (a.equals(b)) return 0;
                if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
                    return 1;
                } else return -1;
            }
```

It does not work either. Some of the values are still `null`. Besides, this workaround might potentially have logical problems.

Anyone can propose a fully working solution to my problem? I'd like the sort by value function to work and the `get` method to work at the same time.

Comment: Why/how would you sort a Map by value? I don't think that even makes sense... Isn't that what Lists and Sets are for?  Just call _Map.values()_ and add the results to a _TreeSet_ or an ordered _List_.

Comment: @jahroy How would you relate the sorted values back to their corresponding keys? I don't want to maintain relationship between key and value manually.

Comment: OK... so you want _the keys_ to be sorted based on the order of the values.  I _guess_ I understand what you want now.

Comment: In that case, you should just use this: `return base.get(a).compareTo(base.get(b))`

Comment: @jahroy If you have better solutions than using maps, it would be nice as well :)

Comment: I just added an answer... You want to use `Integer.compareTo()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your compare function, when the values are equal, you should then compare the keys. This will ensure that different keys having the same value will not be "merged", because it disambiguates entries that would otherwise compare equal.

For example:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        Integer x = base.get(a);
        Integer y = base.get(b);
        if (x.equals(y)) {
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
        return x.compareTo(y);
    }
```

(you'll need to modify the code above to match your policy for null values)

Note that your approach of sorting on values is pretty fragile, though. Your "sorted" map will not support addition of new entries, which could be pretty confusing.

Answer (score 4):

```
base.get(a) ==  base.get(b)
```

This code compares boxed `Integer`s by reference.

Change it to `base.get(a).equals(base.get(b))` and it should work.

Comment: I don't think it's the real problem :)

Comment: @TerryLi: No; the `==` operator does not autounbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return base.get(a).compareTo(base.get(b));
```

---

To demonstrate that you are incorrect about auto-unboxing:

```
Integer a = new Integer(2);
Integer b = new Integer(2);
boolean isEqual = ( a == b );
System.out.println("equal: " + isEqual);
System.out.println("a: " + a);
System.out.println("b: " + b);
```

My output is:

```
equal: false
a: 2
b: 2
```

Comment: It has the same key merging problem. By the way, you can compare `Integer` objects directly using `==`.

Comment: Good point! I didn't know that. But my problem persists even with the correct comparison method :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
HashMap<String, Integer> h = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
h.put("z",30);
h.put("e",10);
h.put("b",20);
h.put("c",20);
List<Map.Entry> a = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>(h.entrySet());
Collections.sort(a,
         new Comparator() {
             public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                 Map.Entry e1 = (Map.Entry) o1;
                 Map.Entry e2 = (Map.Entry) o2;
                 return ((Comparable) e1.getValue()).compareTo(e2.getValue());
             }
         });

for (Map.Entry e : a) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
}
```

Ouptut:

```
e 10
b 20
c 20
z 30
```