# Sorting multidimensional array with index and value

Tags: java

I have an multidimensional array consists of key and value.
Based on sort value i have to arrange key values
For Eg:

```
Multidimensional array:
key Value
1    5
4    2
3    4
8    1
6    2

I have to arrange keys based ascending order of values 
Answer:
8 1
4 2
6 2
3 4
1 5
```

Comment: Use HashMap and sort by value.

Comment: In Java, C++, or C ? Did you try something ?

Comment: Why three languages tag here?

Comment: @JeevanRoydsouza next time put relevant tags only. I removed other tags

Comment: @Ruchira..I want in java

Comment: And what is your approach?

Comment: This link could help as well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852725/java-map-sort-by-value

Comment: @Vladimir Tikhomirov Thank You for the link.Its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
static class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Integer> base;

    ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        Integer x = base.get(a);
        Integer y = base.get(b);
        if (x.equals(y)) {
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
        return x.compareTo(y);
    }
}


HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
ValueComparator vc = new ValueComparator(map);
TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(vc);

map.put("z",30);
map.put("e",10);
map.put("b",20);
map.put("c",20);

sorted.putAll(map);

for (String key : sorted.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + " : " + sorted.get(key)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a TreeMap in which you put values mapped to keys
(so you reverse their meanings for your case).

Just add the elements in the TreeMap and you will have them sorted.

This will work if you don't have multiple keys mapped to the same value
(key/value in this last sentence is used in your meaning, not in the usual Map meaning).

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
Integer[][] array ={{1,5},{4,2},{3,4},{8,1},{6,2}};
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
    return o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

**Output**

```
[[8, 1], [4, 2], [6, 2], [3, 4], [1, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad collection. You should have used map.

Comment: Any other way is there for doing other then hash map?

Comment: Well, you can do this with every collection (or combination of them) but for key/value pairs maps are natural choice. You do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So you are telling me to use my own logic instead of using hashmap?