# TreeMap<Integer, Integer> remove not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the top 10 elements of a TreeMap by executing this loop:

```
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = sortMap(m);
        String outString = "";
        int count = 10;
        while (count > 0) {
            count--;
            Integer k = sortedMap.firstKey();
            outString += String.valueOf(k);
            sortedMap.remove(k);
            if (count != 0) {
                outString += ",";
            }
        }

        System.out.println("outVal is " + outVal);
```

This prints `outVal is 11377,11377,11377,11377,11377,11377,11377,11377,11377,11377`
`Integer` implements `Comparable`, so why might `remove` not be working?

**UPDATE** Here's my `sortMap` implementation:

```
        public static TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sortMap(HashMap<Integer, Integer> map) {
           ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
           TreeMap<Integer,Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>(bvc);
           sorted_map.putAll(map);
           return sorted_map;
        }

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    java.util.Map<Integer, Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator(java.util.Map<Integer, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** This was helpful: [Java Map sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852725/java-map-sort-by-value).

Comment: Could you show your `sortMap` method? I think the problem is here, and not with the snippet of code you provided.

Comment: `outVal` is not defined in this code snippet. Did you mean `outString`?

Comment: I corrected the mistake mentioned by dimoniy, and the output is correct on my side.

Comment: And can you confirm that that's `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: "*// returning 0 would merge keys*" => this is the reason. It won't merge identical keys but won't remove a key either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
    if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    } // returning 0 would merge keys
}
```

This comparator is flawed as (quite apart from it being inconsistent with `equals`) it does not satisfy the comparator contract which states that `compare(a,b) > 0` implies `compare(b,a) < 0` and vice versa.  And since `TreeMap` relies on the comparator returning 0 to find the key you're trying to `remove()` it will never be able to remove anything - no matter what key you try and search for the map will never think that the key is present.

Comment: This is why this approach to sorting a `Map` is pretty inevitably doomed to failure.  Use an approach like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2581754/869736 .

Answer (score 4):

After your edit it is clear that your custom comparator is the culprit. What you actually want to achieve is collecting the keys of the ten highest *values* in the map.

But, your approach is needlessly roundabout, if I may say. You already have some map `m`, which is your starting point. So what you need is just collect its `entrySet`, sort it by value, and take the first ten elements:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

final List<Entry<Integer,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(m.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
  @Override public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
  }});
final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
String delimiter = "";
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e : list.subList(0, 10)) {
  b.append(delimiter).append(e.getKey());
  delimiter = ",";
}
System.out.println(b);
```

Note that a one-shot sort is more efficient than inserting elements one by one into a binary search tree.

I am also using `StringBuilder`, which is again more efficient than recreating a full `String` in each step.

Comment: You don't need to sort at all - [new ArrayList(Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) states *Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,* **in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.**

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon which is fine if the _original_ `m` is already a `SortedMap`, but that is not clear from the question.

Comment: And you could use `for(int k : list.subList(0, limit))` and get rid of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

**i tried like following it worked for me**

```
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
    String outString = "";
    sortedMap.put(1, 10);
    sortedMap.put(2, 20);
    sortedMap.put(3, 30);
    sortedMap.put(4, 40);
    sortedMap.put(5, 50);
    int count = 5;
    while (count > 0) {
        count--;
        Integer k = sortedMap.firstKey();
        outString += sortedMap.get(k);//String.valueOf(k);
        sortedMap.remove(k);
        if (count != 0) {
            outString += ",";
        }
    }

    System.out.println("outVal is " + outString);
    System.out.println(sortedMap.size());
```

Comment: The OP's case is different as they are using a custom comparator for the TreeSet.

Comment: I'm sorting by value, not key.

Comment: But Rose according to your problem removal of items were not working