# How to print HashMap elements from max to min

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a dataset like this:

```
water, 5
eggs, 3
juice, 7
bread, 4
```

i save all of these in

```
HashMap<String, Integer> dataSet = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Now i want to create a function to print the elements from max integer to min:

```
juice, 7
water, 5
bread, 4
eggs, 3
```

i think that the easiest way to do this is to create a copy of HashMap dataSet and then i must run the HashMapCopy, find the max, print the max element and the remove it from the list.

```
private static void printMaxToMin(){
    dataSetCopy = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>(dataSet);

}
```

How can i run all the list, find the max, print the pair of elements with the max value every time and then delete it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Map sort by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852725/java-map-sort-by-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is one way of sorting by value.

```
dataSet.entrySet().stream()
          .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
          .forEach(x -> {
               System.out.println(x.getKey() + ","+ x.getValue());
          });
```

result:

```
juice,7
water,5
bread,4
eggs,3
```

Comment: this answer is definately better than mine. You should use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would certainly work. A bit nicer would be to add all the elements to a list and then sort it.

To do this, make a wrapper class containing a String and an Integer that implements Comparable. For example, using Integer compare and if they are equal String compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a Map sort automatically by a value (unless you create a custom map type). I would recommend [sorting the map by its values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java) everytime you need to print the map.